VertexAI authentication
I am currently referring to the codelab Build a Q&A App with Multi-Modal RAG using Gemini Pro which uses
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

to authenticate.
I also see genai reference implement as such
import google.generativeai as genai
import os

genai.configure(api_key=os.environ["GEMINI_API_KEY"])

How can I authenticate when using vertexAI?
I have access to API key and service account created with required roles.


google.generativeai as genai   <--- is ai studio gemini api and not Vertext nor is it langchain.   your mixing things up.     2. How to do it why not just follow the codelab you linked?


HI ,use  'gcloud auth application-default login ` to authenticate  and you can refer to this doc also  and follow this community post once  .

Is this issues is resolved or do you still need help ?

As you are already part of Google Cloud ecosystem, I believe you will be using services like Cloud Run to host your Application. Cloud Run will use a designated service account to run your application.
(Your TODO) If you provide minimum requirement permission to this service account, then it will be enough to host & run your without the need for API Keys.
If it help, I have written a short blog post that might help your and its source code is hosted in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/devrel-demos
